# OutOfMemoryError behavior in Java

Tags: java

I always thought that an `OutOfMemoryError` restarts the JVM.
But I am seeing a behavior where an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs this is not caught from the code (actually I don't even know if this is possible)
and the `JVM` continues (a core dump is produced though).
Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OutOfMemoryError reports to one thread that its memory allocation failed.

```
int count = 0;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    try {
        long[] longs = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        count++;
    }
}
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.printf("Got %,d OutOfMemoryErrors in %.1f seconds%n", count, time/1e3);
```

prints

```
Got 10,000,000 OutOfMemoryErrors in 3.9 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

`OutOfMemoryError` is an exception just like any other. It certainly doesn't restart the JVM. It may possibly cause the thread in which it occurs to end, but that happens only if it is not caught anywhere. What you probably see is not a core dump, but merely the stack trace of the exception that was caught and its stack trace explicitly printed using `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: So when I occusionally see a JVM restart, what does that mean?

Comment: That means that a JVM launcher is in effect that explicitly takes care of the restarting. It has nothing to do with Java itself.

Comment: So you are saying that even though the dump says that the heap is exausted, the JVM still does not terminate by itself?What can it do after this condition?

Comment: The heap is not required for execution to continue. As long as you don't allocate anything, you can go on. In practice, as soon as the OOME happens, the call stack unwinds and many objects become unreachable. An ensuing GC run reclaims the memory. How much this helps is of course not answerable in general.

Comment: Then what does it mean when the dump reports that the heap is exausted?

Comment: 1. It's not a dump, but a stack trace. 2. It means that the heap is indeed exhausted. In more precise terms, the requested memory allocation failed.

Comment: It means the heap was exhausted once (and your program is likely to be in a poor state)

Comment: Are you also saying that an application should try to `catch(Throwable)` instead of `catch(Exception)`. I always read that to try to catch `Error` is bad design

Comment: When implementing an exception barrier, such as at the top level of a web request handler, it would be bad design **not** to catch it. If you don't catch it, your server may collapse due to a minor coding bug that causes a stack overflow or an out-of-memory condition.

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemory is just an Error that is thrown when an object could not be instanciated due to a lack of available memory. This does not stop the JVM, just like no other exception or error does.

Answer (score 1):

No Throwable ever restarts a JVM. The OutOfMemoryError is like every other runtime exception or error: it propagates the call stack until it's caught. And if it isn't, then the thread's UncaughtExceptionHandler handles this exception, usually by terminating the thread and printing the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: So when I occusionally see a JVM restart, what does that mean?

Comment: Probably that you have some script or tool detecting that the JVM doesn't run anymore, and which restarts it. A JVM doesn't restart by itself. It could crash completely, but not restart.

Comment: So you are saying that even though the dump says that the heap is exausted, the JVM still does not terminate by itself?What can it do after this condition?

Comment: An OutOfMemoryError doesn't say that the heap is exhausted. It says that you asked for some memory, and that it wasn't possible to allocate it. If you have some thread asking for 1 GB of memory, and this thread dies because there is only 980 MBs available, other threads could continue running without any problem.

Comment: But the overall report of the dump says that there is no heap left

Comment: There is not enough memory available in the heap to honor a request for some amount of memory. But, as I already said and as Marko said, there might be enough memory available to honor other requests for less memory, and the fact that the exception is thrown causes the end of the execution of an entire call stask, which could make lots of objects eligible for GC, and thus plenty of memory available. If you go to a restaurant with 49 friends and ask for 50 seats. The restaurant will tell you that it's not possible to honor this request. That doesn't prevent the restaurent for accepting people.

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryError or any exception never restart the JVM.

> I am seeing a behavior where an OutOfMemoryError occurs this is not caught from the code

---->  [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) inherits `java.lang.Error`. Errors describe environmental problems which may be rare or difficult to recover from such as running out of computer memory. You are not expected to handle Error class objects but you should handle them with `Throwable`. These should be regarded as 
environmental flaws.

Have a look on [Exception Hierarchy](http://www.sentex.net/~pkomisar/J2/3_Exceptions.html).

Comment: A well-designed application is very much required to handle any Throwables, including OOME's. Would you like to see your server crash just because a single request OOME'd or SOE'd? I wouldn't, either.